# Do you know what this "connector piece" is called and where to buy it?

Tags: plumbing, water, filter, connectors, water-filtration

Does anyone know what the "connector piece" mentioned in this video at 6min 11s is called: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HIOiyPKUbQ&t=6m10s

And where to buy it?

I could not find it Lowe's, Home Depot, Alkaviva, or the place that sold the water filter unit.

I don't mind buying the entire kit if I have to, but I just can't find where I can buy it from.

Thank you and Happy Holidays :)

Update 1:
Sorry, but I should clarify that the Shark Bit quick connect did not work because the threaded end did not reach far enough in to the spout side.
[image]

I have a video too, but StackExchange won't allow videos.

Update 2:
I tried to contact the manufacturer but there was a language barrier so not much information was exchanged.  I also tried contacting the person who posted the video, but have not received a response.

Comment: "push to connect" fittings. Home Depot, Lowes, etc definitely have them.

Comment: @Gunner thank you for the prompt response and input.  Sorry, I was unclear in my question.  I've updated it with information on what happened when I tried to Shark Bit quick connect.  Do you know of any workarounds for the threaded side?  Thank you again for your time and enjoy the rest of 2019 :)

Comment: Your first coarse of action should be to go to manufacturers web site or try to contact them.

Comment: @AlaskaMan thanks. We tried that. :)

Comment: @AL That would have been pertinent info to include in your question. *And what happened when you did try that ?* Did you try to contact the person who post the video you linked to?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thanks for the tip.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/4" quick connect fitting available all good plumbing and hardware stores, just make sure you cut the tube square and it is pushed in all the way.

Comment: thank you for the quick response and input.  I tried the normal Shark Bit quick connect adapters but the threaded side was not compatible.  I've updated the question with this information; sorry I did not have that information in earlier.  Do you know of a way to adjust for this?  Thanks again for your time and enjoy the rest of 2019 :)

Comment: Wow...how were you able to tell it's 1/4"?  Is that standard?  I always have to bring in the entire piece in to compare sizes.